# "Unhandled Event Loop Exception" when doing anything in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt, event-loop

I'm getting this "Unhandled Event Loop Exception" error when I do very minimal things with my xml layout in Android (Eclipse 3.6.2). Everything I do makes this error come up. And the dialog box will be something like "Error...35" or something. It's as simple as moving an ImageView around in the Graphical Editor or even typing xml (every keystroke creates a new error). It's not just one error either. it's 7 or 8 of these "Unhandled Event Loop Exception" errors all in a row.

Here's the code inside the Error Log errors.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86


Error
Thu Mar 01 17:28:10 CST 2012
Unhandled event loop exception

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalStateException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionMapping.toImageLine(ProjectionMapping.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.modelLine2WidgetLine(TextViewer.java:5264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.modelLine2WidgetLine(StructuredTextViewer.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.JFaceTextUtil.modelLineToWidgetLine(JFaceTextUtil.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.source.DiffPainter.paintLine(DiffPainter.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.internal.text.source.DiffPainter.paint(DiffPainter.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberChangeRulerColumn.doPaint(LineNumberChangeRulerColumn.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn.doubleBufferPaint(LineNumberRulerColumn.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn.redraw(LineNumberRulerColumn.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.LineNumberRulerColumn$1.run(LineNumberRulerColumn.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue,but it works fine when i Closed and restarted my Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on any XML file, then it is probably a problem in the XML editor. Either way, if you try editing the XML with the built-in plain text editor, it may work. Also, if it is a bug of any kind, updating eclipse and the android plug-in may help. Eclipse 3.7 is out.